# Find out version of composer used to build composer.lock file

Tags: php, composer-php

Most of my projects are built using Composer 1. Now that I am upgrading to Composer 2, I would like to run a command to get the version of Composer that was used to build the project. What is the best way to get the version? I believe the version is stored in `plugin-api-version` but not sure what is the best way to get that. Was hoping that there was a Composer command to read that.

Comment: Why? The version of Composer used in the build should not matter.

Comment: Some of my sites don't work with Composer 2.

Comment: So use Composer 1.x, there were no BC breaks regarding composer.lock between 1 and 2. If you have an actual, demonstrable problem running across both versions you should detail _that_, rather than asking about inconsequential version checking.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not generate one lock file with v1, and then from the same composer.json using v2, and then check for possible differences?

Comment: It seems like a weird requirement. If you need a project to use a specific version of composer, for whatever reason, you need to declare it on the `require` section of your `composer.json`. Whatever was used to generate the lock file in the past is not a declaration of incompatibility with the v2 api. The vast majority of projects that used to use composer v1 are able to use composer v2 without any change.